# SQL remove text, leave number

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have some old data in an access database that is very poorly formated. There is a packSize column with mixed data. Sometimes it says "2 pack", sometimes "4 pk", sometimes "3", etc. What I would like to do is run an SQL command to remove all the text and leave just the number. How should I go about this?

Comment: Try the `val` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the `VAL` command can work if the field always starts with numeric values, this may not always be the case.  Sample usage:

```
UPDATE Table SET field = Val(field)
```

If you want to strip out all non-numeric values from a string/field, this is a method I've used in the past (directly from Microsoft):

```
Function RemoveAlphas (ByVal AlphaNum as Variant)

   Dim Clean As String
   Dim Pos, A_Char$

   Pos = 1
   If IsNull(AlphaNum) Then Exit Function

   For Pos = 1 To Len(AlphaNum)
      A_Char$ = Mid(AlphaNum, Pos, 1)
      If A_Char$ >= "0" And A_Char$ <= "9" Then
         Clean$ = Clean$ + A_Char$
      End If
   Next Pos

   RemoveAlphas = Clean$

End Function
```

And:

> How to Use the RemoveAlphas() Function in an Update Query
>
> Create a new query based on the table with the phone number field.
>   Place the phone number field in the first column of the query grid. On
>   the Query menu, click Update. In the Update To row, enter the
>   following for a field named Phone: RemoveAlphas([Phone]) Run the
>   query.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210537

Comment: Thanks @sgeddes, however, the data does indeed all start with a number, so I think I'm safe with `val`